# Is it possible to define one AUTOSAR Runnable for many components per Task?

Tags: autosar

Here is the scenario...

I need for each task 2 different runnables...

```
- First : to receive data at specific times at the beginning of the task.

- Second: to send data at specific times at the end of the task.
```

each one of these runnables shall make the data available for the different components processes at the beginning of the task (the same as implicit receive mode for sender receiver interface but with some filtering that can't be achieved using filter attribute) or send the data only at specific times at the end of the tasks.

Now how can I handle this? shall I define these runnables per component? or make the communication between all components pass through this common component that is supposed to handle send and receive timing?

I am new to the AUTOSAR so Please let me know what can be the best solution for this.

Comment: No offense, but this hardly makes any sense. It is not possible to „model the data send and receive in one component“ and have the „send/receive processes defined in another component“. There must be a misunderstanding about the nature of the two components (respectively the concept of a component as such) or else the question is phrased in a way that invites misunderstandings. Also, what is the meaning of „process“ in your understanding?

Comment: I totally understand what you mean, that confuse me either. what I meant be process is runnable. i just don't want to make all communication pass through one component to handle the timing part so I thought that it might be another solution to do that without the need to add more communication interfaces or more runnables. i hope it is clear now.

Comment: Nobody forces you to let all RunnableEntities of one software-component run in the same task. That would even be a rare exception. Maybe you can use the task mapping of RunnableEntities (or better: the RTEEvents that trigger these RunnableEntities) to different tasks to your advantage.

Answer (score 0):

> ... make the communication between all components pass through this common component that is supposed to *handle send and receive timing*?

That's what I see a lot over the last years. A lot of developers doing communication stacks do not understand the features and actually reimplement something in the SWCs that is actually available and done since years in the ComStacks .. even in Vectors CANbedded stack (in IL (Interaction Layer)). It makes the SWCs so much dependent on the communication, that the probability of changes is very high.

The timeout handling is handled by the IL and AUTOSAR Com according to the SystemDescription/EcuExtract (and old DBC files) PduTiming, IPDU transmission mode and signal transfer properties.

IPDU Transmission modes:
* NONE  --> triggered not by Com, but manually by Com_TriggerIPDUSend()
* PERIODIC --> triggered cyclically by Com according to configure time period
* DIRECT  --> triggered on "Event" of configured signals (TRIGGERED*)
* MIXED (PERIODIC + DIRECT)  --> "EventPeriodic" .. this also includes a possible MDT (Minimum Time Delay)

Just to name some Signal Property values:
* PENDING - in and IPDU TxMode MIXED this does not trigger an event, therefore pending til next transmission event (or just with next message cycle)
* TRIGGERED - like former DBC "OnWrite"
* TRIGGERED_ON_CHANGE - like former DBC "OnChange", so only if the value changed compared to last value

AUTOSAR Com also can monitor receive IPDUs according to configured  time period.

IpduGroups can be used to enable/disable IPDU transmission and IPDU RxDeadline Monitoring (Timeout handling).

So, in the end, most SWCs do not really need to care about the receive / transmission times .. they just write/read to/from their ports, and that's it.

Another good feature is the SignalGroup handling, which removes the burden to keep complex data (structures) in sync. Formerly, someone would probably have locked the interrupts until all the data is updated in the message.

E2E Protection can now be handled by the E2E Transformers.

So, SWCs can be modeled on VFB (Virtual Function Bus) level, and then mapped to ECUs. Their connections stay the same, but if the SWCs communicate just by Intra-ECU over RTE within the same ECU, or by Inter-ECU across ECU boundaries by ComStack is completely irrelevant to the SWCs.
SWCs can use dataReceivedEvents or dataReceiveErrorEvents to get informed about reception or reception errors (e.g. Timeout) and dataSendCompletedEvent about transmission completion. Or they can also just "poll" by checking the RTE return code of the Rte_Read/Write calls.

Together with the RTE features of DataTransformations, Data/PortMapping and conversions, it should be much easier to have reconfigurable SW without changing the SWCs all the time.

It will also be easier to move SWCs around, no matter if moving them to another core on a multicore processor (with a MultiCore OS and MultiCore RTE) or moving functions from sensors to a high-performance central ECU.

Gateway routing relations on PDU level would not even need any SWCs, this can be handled by configuring PduR routing relations, and exchanging here a POSTBUILD-configuration. Even signal based routing in Com can be done like this.

Comment: First i would like to thank you for your answer!
But it would be better if you don't judge people you know nothing about them or about what they are trying to do even if the question is confusing or very trivial we are here to ask and support not to judge!
What i am trying to do is not that simple and not related to the COM stack. It is an intra-ECU communication between components and within components through the RTE VFB.
And just for your information it is something that will be added in the next releases of AUTOSAR and not supported in any available releases.